# Scala Spark: How do I bootstrap sample from a column of a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am looking to sample values, with replacement, from a column of a Spark DataFrame, using the Scala programming language in a Jupyter Notebook setting in a cluster environment. How do I do this?

I tried the following function that I found online:

```
import scala.util

def bootstrapMean(originalData: Array[Double]): Double = {
  val n = originalData.length

  def draw: Double = originalData(util.Random.nextInt(n))

  // a tail recursive loop to randomly draw and add a value to the accumulating sum
  def drawAndSumValues(current: Int, acc: Double = 0D): Double = {
    if (current == 0) acc
    else drawAndSumValues(current - 1, acc + draw)
  }
  drawAndSumValues(n) / n
}
```

Like so:

```
val data = stack.select("column_with_values").collect.map(_.toSeq).flatten
val m = 10
val bootstraps = Vector.fill(m)(bootstrapMean(data))
```

But I get the error:

```
An error was encountered:
<console>:47: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[Any]
 required: Array[Double]
Note: Any >: Double, but class Array is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: Double`. (SLS 3.2.10)
       val bootstraps = Vector.fill(m)(bootstrapMean(data))
```

Not sure how to debug this, and whether I should bother to or try another approach. I'm looking for ideas/documentation/code. Thanks.

**Update:**

How do I put the user mck's solution below, in a for loop? I tried the following:

```
var bootstrap_container = Seq()
var a = 1
for( a <- 1 until 3){
    var sampled = stack_b.select("diff_hours").sample(withReplacement = true, fraction = 0.5, seed = a)
    var smpl_average = sampled.select(avg("diff_hours")).collect()(0)(0)
    var bootstrap_smpls = bootstrap_container.union(Seq(smpl_average)).collect()
}
bootstrap_smpls
```

but that gives an error:

```
<console>:49: error: not enough arguments for method collect: (pf: PartialFunction[Any,B])(implicit bf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Seq[Any],B,That])That.
Unspecified value parameter pf.
           var bootstrap_smpls = bootstrap_container.union(Seq(smpl_average)).collect()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sample` method of dataframes, for example, if you want to sample with replacement and with a fraction of 0.5:

```
val sampled = stack.select("column_with_values").sample(true, 0.5)
```

To get the mean, you can do:

```
val col_average = sampled.select(avg("column_with_values")).collect()(0)(0)
```

**EDIT**:

```
var bootstrap_container = List[Double]()
var a = 1
for( a <- 1 until 3){
    var sampled = stack_b2.select("diff_hours").sample(withReplacement = true, fraction = 0.5, seed = a)
    var smpl_average = sampled.select(avg("diff_hours")).collect()(0)(0)
    bootstrap_container = bootstrap_container :+ smpl_average.asInstanceOf[Double]
}
var mean_bootstrap = bootstrap_container.reduce(_ + _) / bootstrap_container.length
```

Comment: This helped. But how do you put this into a loop to generate x samples? I thought it would be trivial to do but ended up being beyond my present capability.

Comment: @user2205916 can't you just put it into a for loop? if you call it again it should give you a different sample

Comment: how? I updated my question to show the for loop code that I tried.

Comment: thank you. I am helpless, apparently but how do you find the average of the elements of `bootstrap_container`? Also, more generally, Python has `dir(object)` to find out all of the functions it can be used with. What is the equivalent for Scala in a Notebook environment?

Comment: `bootstrap_container.reduce(_ + _) / bootstrap_container.length` will give you the average. If you want to learn scala I'd suggest reading the docs, going through tutorials, and searching for things that you want to achieve on SO/Google.

Comment: @user2205916 also see edited answer, you need to have `double` type in the container, but not `any`, otherwise the average calculation doesn't work. Scala is a typed language, unlike python which is quite lax on typing.